# Circuit to throw out 1st bit of every 17-bit sequence?

Tags: digital-logic, digital-communications, digital-potentiometer

I have a system that currently uses two Maxim DS1867 digital potentiometers in a daisy-chain configuration.  In a new addition to the system I would like to use a new digital potentiometer part like the Analog Devices AD5142 for availability and reduced footprint size.  Both of these parts have two (2) 8-bit potentiometers, but the problem is that the DS1867 uses a 17-bit serial communication string with the first bit being an unused stack select bit, while the AD5142 uses only 16-bits in its communication stream.  This wouldn't be a problem if only one part were used but I need to be able to daisy-chain the parts.

What sort of circuit should I be looking at that could throw out the first bit of every 17-bit sequence so that I can use the existing data stream?

Comment: wow, this is an interesting one. do you not have access to the serial communications from the system??

Comment: @KyranF in theory the serial communication could be changed, however due to personnel changes doing so would be a time-consuming process.  So I'm investigating what could be done to make the new part compatible with the legacy communication.

Comment: So you want to want to truncate the 17-bit strings to 16 bits each and then concatenate them in order to yield a contiguous 32 bit string to stream?

Comment: making a whole new PCB though, and the amount of crazy components or ICs you might need to do this.. I think it's worth at least investigating the software side of this problem. In terms of implementing a 1st bit dropper, perhaps you can use a simple latch (on first rising edge) and unlatch (on second rising edge) with P channel FET or a  single bit non-inverting line driver (with an enable pin) to disconnect during the first bit transmission, but reconnect for the next 16 bits. Use a hex counter to count the 17 bits total and reset the entire logic circuit ready for the next packet

Comment: @EMFields yes that is essentially what needs to be done

Comment: Does communication use stop and start bits? If the 17th bit is unused you can use it as an extra stop bit.

Comment: @jippie no there are no start or stop bits, just the 1st unused stack-select bit and then two 8-bit words containing the potentiometers value.

Comment: Can you not modify the program controlling the communication? It looks like DS1867's use a protocol very similar to SPI, and chaining SPI devices of different bit-widths isn't a problem.

Answer (score 4):

For each 16 bit device (other than the final one) put a single D type flip flop on the output and use it's output as feed to the next 16 bit device. The d type will soak up each 17th bit or, looking in a different way, the d type makes the 16 bit device a 17 bit device.

Comment: That's not what he wants, though. He already has two 17 bit words that he concatenates and sends to two Maxim pots as a single 34 bit serial word. What he's got now are two Analog Devices pots which want to see 16 bit words each, so he wants a way to strip the first bit off of each 17 bit word, then concatenate the now 16 bit words and send them as a single 32 bit serial word to the AD pots.

Comment: @emfields I think, by adding a d type, after each device it soaks up the 17th bit. I'm not 100% confident because I'm on holiday on an android phone.

Answer (score 0):

If you have available the 34 bit serial data stream, data clock, and you must do it in hardware, a brute-force way would be to read the 34 bits into a 34 bit serial-in parallel-out shift register, then to broadside load the 32 desired bits into a 32 bit parallel-in serial-out shift register and shift them out as a single 32 bit word to the daisy-chained pots.